# Mongoosejs post save after create

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, q

I am using Q promise library for chaining queries. I have post hook that adds to new document new property.

```
  MyModel.create(data)
          .then(function(data) {
                // <------------------ post hook has not been triggered yet
                return MySchema.findById(data._id); // trying to get the new document 
          })
         .then(function(data) {
              // <------------------ post hook has not been triggered yet
              reply(null, data); // <- my callback
         });
         .done()
         // <------------------ post hook has triggered!!!
```

After new document has been created post hook not triggering, and in node console I see that it triggers after this chain ends.

How can I ensure post hook triggers before I can return new document?

**UPDATE:** my postsave hook is asynchronous, and mongoose is not waiting for it. There is no other way to use post hook without EventEmitter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to hold on to the original promise d.resolve() until the post hook finishes.

What I mean by that is actually wait in the `MyModel.create` method. You return d.promise, but do not resolve it. You wait there until your post hook is done, and then resolve the promise.

Now, how to check if your postsave hook is done? I don't know. Can you give it a callback as a param? So that the posthook can call this method once it's done, and you can resolve your original promise.
The other method is to have your .create method poll or whatever until the posthook is triggered.

Now, as for why it doesn't trigger, also you need to show more of the code. What's in the posthook?

Comment: Already have made solution with emitting custom event, when posthook is done. here http://pastebin.com/bGh3mPxJ mongoose executes all hooks and do not wait until they finished. So there is no way to know when document is ready.